# How to change Date Display format of new Date()

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I am new to MEAN Stack

I am using new date() function to get date but I don't want to display time off-set .

[image]

Comment: use filters and you can find full details about date functions https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Tell me an example of how to display the date? like "12-12-2017"

Comment: Where is evidence of research?

Comment: Date objects allow you to get all of the localised information rather easily. Of course you could always use a third-party library to simplify things even further. But in this case I don't think that's even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angular date filters : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

For Example:

```
{{new Date() || date:'medium' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `.substring()` to get the desired formatted value or use following

```
var d = new Date();

var DayOfMonth = d.getDate();
var DayOfWeek = d.getDay();
var Month = d.getMonth();
var Year = d.getFullYear();
var Hours = d.getHours();
var Minutes = d.getMinutes();
var Seconds = d.getSeconds();
```

Comment: The string given by the OP (ending in Z) is in a specific format that is universal (by UTC AFAIK). You can get the correct one to parse by using `d.toLocaleString()`. The variables in your answer should already be locale-correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Angular Moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) Js and [Moment Js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) it might be helpful.

You can convert this as the below using moment js

```
var date = new date();
var formateddate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

To use this you have to add Angular moment in your project and which is explained in above link how to add using nuget or bower or npm.